# Coloring with hsl and functions with my php code

Tags: php, html

I have this code done, however it is not working the way I would like. I am trying to color a piece of a string.  The color is decided by a function `getcolor`, which is decided by a function called raw transform, which will transforma  raw score into a score from 1-9 for my switch case. Can anyone offer some help? `$col` is assigned by another function- for arguments sake lets say it is defined as: `$col= 0`.

```
<?php

$raw= 650;
function rawtransform($raw) {
  $score = (int)($raw/50)-9;
}
    //==========================================================================
//            Function to decide which color system                         //
//==========================================================================   
function getcolor($score, $col)
{
switch ($score){
// to return the function best way is to declare the case outcome as a variable eg.$truecol
case 1: /*500-550(Raw Score)*/
    $truecol="<span style=\"color: hsl($col,100%,90%);\">";
    break;
case 2: //550-600
    $truecol="<span style=\"color: hsl($col,100%,80%);\">";
    break;
case 3: //600-650
    $truecol="<span style=\"color: hsl($col,100%,70%);\">";
    break;
case 4: //650-700
    $truecol="<span style=\"color: hsl($col,100%,60%);\">";
    break;
case 5: //700-750
    $truecol="<span style=\"color: hsl($col,100%,50%);\">";
    break;
case 6: //750-800
    $truecol="<span style=\"color: hsl($col,100%,40%);\">";
    break;
case 6: //800-850
    $truecol="<span style=\"color: hsl($col,100%,30%);\">";
    break;
case 7: //850-900;
    break;
case 8: //900-950
    $truecol="<span style=\"color: hsl($col,100%,20%);\">";
    break;
case 9: //950-1000
    $truecol="<span style=\"color: hsl($col,100%,10%);\">";
    break;
   }
}

   $query="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC";

$seq=chunk_split($query,50,"<br />");
getcolor($score);
function colorSequence ($seq,$position,$truecol,$TFBSlength){
    $nucleotides = str_split($seq);
    foreach ($nucleotides as $index => $nucl){
        if ($index == $position){
            echo $truecol;
        }
        if ($index == $position + $TFBSlength){
            echo "</span>";
        }

        echo $nucl;
    }
    echo "\n";
}
colorSequence($seq,49,$truecol,1);
?>
```

The output does not include the coloring of the selcted nucleotides.  Anyone know why?

Comment: You haven't explained what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not assign the return value of `getcolor($score);` to a variable. I bet it should be like `$truecol = getcolor($score);` before calling `colorSequence($seq,49,$truecol,1);`.

Comment: Try to learn programming first: your `getcolor()` doesn't return a value; you don't pass in a second parameter when calling that function; etc. – that are programming basic…

Comment: By decalring each case as the variable $truecol am I not returning it ?

Comment: No, by returning a value, you'll return it: `function getAbc() { return $abc; }` See also: http://de2.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php